# mongodb update exception 'document fragment is too large'

Tags: php, windows, mongodb

Updating my collection record field with 'MongoBinData', exception is triggered:
"document fragment is too large: 21216456, max: 16777216"
I find some web discussion about 'allowDiskUse:true' for aggregate, but nothing ubout 'update'.
Here a part of code in PHP:

```
try {
    $criteria = array( '_id' => $intReleaseId);
    $fileData =  file_get_contents( $_FILES[ $fileKey]["tmp_name"]);
    $mongoBinData = new MongoBinData( $fileData, MongoBinData::GENERIC)
    $docItem['data'] = $mongoBinData;
    $docItem['fileType'] = $strFileType;
    $docItem['fileSize'] = $intFileSize;
    $docItem['fileExtension'] = $strFileExtension;
    $docItem['fileName'] = $strFileName;
    $options = array( "upsert" => true, 
        'safe' => true, 'fsync' => true, 
        'allowDiskUse' => true ); // this option doesn't change anything
    $reportJson = self::GetCollection('releases')->update( $criteria, $docItem, $options);
...
```

MongoDb release is db version v3.0.6

Some idea ?

Comment: Is gridFS (MongoGridFS) the solution ?

Comment: The maximum size a MongoDB document can be is 16MB. Looks like your update is attempting to grow a document to 21MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self resolved.
Use gridFS is immediate and simple.

```
$_mongo = new MongoClient();
$_db = $_mongo->selectDB($_mDbName);
$_gridFS = $_db->getGridFS();

/* */
function saveFileData($intReleaseId, $binData) {
    $criteria = array( '_id' => $intReleaseId);
    // if exist or not, remove previous value
    try {
        $_gridFS->remove( $criteria);
        }
    catch(Exception $e) {}
    // store new file content
    $storeByteCompleted = false;
    try {
        $reportId = $_gridFS->storeBytes( 
             $binData, 
             array("_id" => $intReleaseId));
        if ($reportId == $intReleaseId) {
            $storeByteCompleted = true;
            }
    catch(Exception $e) {}
    return $storeByteCompleted;
    }

function loadFileData($intReleaseId) {
    $gridfsFile = null;
    $binData = null;
    try {
        $gridfsFile = $_gridFS->get($intReleaseId);
        }
    catch(Exception $e) {}
    if ($gridfsFile != null) {
        $binData = $gridfsFile->getBytes()
        }
    return $binData;
    }
```

That's all.